# serial port connection is not working in windows with java

Tags: java, windows, serial-port

While connecting serial port of windows 7 using java is not working,

Error setting serial port COM21 state.

The same port is connecting using putty.

Other ports[7,8,9] are able to connect using java and putty.

In java port higher than 9 is not able to connect.

Answer (score 0):

thats actually an operating-system limitation of sorts - i remember an MSDN-article about kernel drivers in which it is told that COM-ports above 9 require the use of a different strategy; which is already transparently used if you write native Microsoft C/C++ - applications. This could very well limit the accessibility in other languages.

You can try accessing the port via links like this :

```
\\\\.\\COM21
```

This should work in most cases, read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/115831 for more info

Comment: without any error-message, further description and/or stacktrace nobody will be able to help you.

Comment: I got port is not found error message , while i added like this \\\\.\\COM21